# Error When Trying To Change Folder Permission

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, file-permissions, lubuntu

I am trying to give a user other than `sudo` read/write access to a folder and subs, if I run the command `sudo chown user1432 /media/newfolder` it throws an error of

> chown changing ownership of '/media/newfolder': Permission Denied

Just to confirm I was using the correct username to change to, I ran the command `whoami` which displayed the username

> user1432

So I know that element is accurate, if I look at `stat /media/newfolder` it shows that `root` is the only user with `drwxr` perms.

What must I do to change the permission from root to another user?  Or even give a different user write permissions?

My fstab reads like this

> //192.168.X.XXX/tonythetiger /media/newfolder cifs username=username,password=passwrd 0 0

Comment: Is `/media/newfolder` really just a folder, or a mount point of another file system (external storage device)?

Comment: @bfrguci - it is a mounted network share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `/media/newfolder` is a mount point of some other file system, e.g. external drives, network shares, etc. It is possible that the file system does not allow permission management. For example, if it is an FAT USB drive, you will not be able to `chown` or `chmod`.

In your case, if it is a network share, you might be able to change its permission or ownership upon mounting it. I am using the `noauto,user,idmap=user` options for my SSHFS network share, so it is not auto mounted upon booting, and the user who mounts it is regarded as the owner. For Samba shares, you may use `uid=<user_name>,gid=<group_name>` to set owner and group.

A few lines from my `fstab`:

```
<user_name>@<host_name>.local:/home/<user_name> /path/to/mount/point fuse.sshfs noauto,user,idmap=user 0 0
//<host_name>/path/to/samba/share /path/to/mount/point_2 cifs noauto,user,credentials=/path/to/samba/.credentials,uid=<user_name>,gid=root 0 0
```

Comment: I am mounting at logon using fstab.  Is there a setting I can alter in there to set my logon as the owner?  This is a Win 10 share.

Comment: Yes, the options I gave you are from my `fstab`. Are you using SSHFS or Samba?

Comment: Not sure...how would I check that?

Comment: @user2676140 Hey, you added it to `fstab` yourself, right? You can see if the "file system" field in your `fstab` says `cifs` or `sshfs`, or whatever else. The third field in the line.

Comment: @user2676140 I gave you 2 examples from my `fstab` in my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: I edited my post to show the syntax I used in my fstab

Comment: @user2676140 Yes, it is Samba. Please see my second example. You can add uid and gid options to it.